# Upgrading solutions and projects

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a Visual Studio 2008 solution, which I want to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012.  I have a few questions:

1. Can you install Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2012 on the
   same PC?
2. I believe there is an "upgrade to Visual Studio 2012" button in 2012.  Is it really as simple as this?
3. Do developers still use Visual Studio 2008?
4. Is it necessary to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 first? i.e. must we purchase this version as well?

I have spent two hours looking on MSDN for an answer to these questions.  Whilst developers do talk about the problems they had with third party components; I cannot find answers to my specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, they can coexist.
2. It's about that simple. Fire up VS 2012 and open the solution. It will ask if you want to upgrade. the upgrade is one-way (i.e. you won't be able to open the solution in VS2008 after the conversion).
3. Probably. I saw a job posting recently that called for VS2008 experience.
4. No.